# Checking whether a linked list is a palindrome - What am I missing here?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Here's my attempted solution to the problem .

```
 public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {

    if(head == null || head.next == null)
        return true;
    ListNode hare = head;
    ListNode tort = head;
    while(hare!=null && hare.next!=null) {
        //System.out.print("Hare "+ hare.val +"tort  "+tort.val);
        hare = hare.next.next;
        tort = tort.next;
    }
    //Tort is the middle of the list
    reverseLL(tort);
    ListNode tmp = tort;
    printList(tmp);
    while(tort!=null) {
        if(head.val!=tort.val)
            return false;
        head = head.next;
        tort = tort.next;
        continue;
    }
    return true;
}

private ListNode reverseLL(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }
    ListNode nextElem = head.next;
    //System.out.println("Processing "+head.val);

    head.next = null;
    ListNode rev = reverseLL(nextElem);
    nextElem.next = head;
    return rev;
}

 private void printList(ListNode head){
        while(head!=null){
            System.out.println("[" +head.val + "]");
            head = head.next;
        }

    }
```

But I'm noticing something pretty weird that I havent been able to figure out. `tort`currently ends up at the middle of the linked list. However, the reversal from `tort` till the end seems to be disconnecting the tort from the rest of the linked list.

For example if input is 1->2->3->4 tort ends up being 3 but printing the list after reversing it from tort only prints 3 ie.  3 is disconnected from the remainder of the list.

I've tested that `reverseLL` separately and it works but when its applied as part of the isPalindrome method. Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

While finding the middle of the linked list in the first while loop, why don't you maintain a pointer to the node previous to tort:

```
ListNode prev_tort = head;
while(hare!=null && hare.next!=null) {
    //System.out.print("Hare "+ hare.val +"tort  "+tort.val);
    hare = hare.next.next;
    prev_tort = tort;
    tort = tort.next;
}
```

Now, when there are even number of elements, hare would be NULL. So, for the odd case, skip the middle node:

```
if(hare != NULL){
     tort = tort.next;
     prev_tort = prev_tort.next;
}
tort = reverseLL(tort);
prev_tort.next = tort;  // only to ensure list is connected
```

and then comes your comparison code.

Also, in the reverseLL() function:

```
ListNode rev = reverseLL(nextElem);
head.next.next = head;
head.next = NULL;

return rev;
```

If I understand correctly, you are trying to check whether the list is palindrome by reversing the second half. In that case, for input 1->2->3->4, shouldn't tort point to 4 after reversing the second half? That's what the above code does (and the list will be: 1->2->4->3).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to check for palindrome *in place*, but you have not stated such requirement so I present a way more straightforward algorithm:

1. Initialize a stack
2. Traverse the list and push each element on top of the stack
3. Until the stack is not empty:

   1. Pop the head of the stack
   2. Compare the popped element with the head of the list
   3. If unequal, return `false`
   4. Pop another element, move one element forward in the list
4. return `true`

Here is a Java implementation with generics:

```
    public <T> boolean isPalindrome(ListNode<T> head) {
        Stack<ListNode<T>> stack = new Stack<>();
        ListNode<T> x = head;
        while(x != null) {
            stack.push(x);
            x = x.next;
        }
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            ListNode<T> el = stack.pop();
            if(el.t != head.t) return false;
            head = head.next;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This algorithm is O(n) in time and O(n) in space.